# MIPS : address out of range error

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to turn this C code:

```
    if (op == '+') {
      acc += val;
    }
```

into MIPS, and I can't figure out what is causing the address out of range error

```
#reads user input for the op
li $v0, 12      # system call number for operator
syscall         # reads the integer
sw $v0, op      # stores the user input in op


lw $t0, op      # stores op in $t0
lbu $t1, '+'        # stores '+' in $t1

# "if" statement
bne $t0, $t1, Else  # branches if op is not equal to +
lw $t2, acc     # stores acc in $t2
lw $t3, val     # stores val in $t3

add $t2, $t2, $t3   # adds $t2 and $t3 and stores the sum in $t2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lbu $t1, '+'
```

'+' is not a valid address. You probably meant

```
li $t1, '+'
```

Anyway remember that any decent C compiler will convert C to MIPS for you.

Comment: thanks, I knew it had to be something small like that. This is for a project I am working on so using the mips_gcc compiler would defeat the purpose